# Datagridview column SortGlyph indicator is hidden behind scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform application with a Datagridview that has 6 columns.  All columns except col. 4 are sortable. Sorting is initiated by clicking on a column header and grid will sort on that column.  All this works.  My problem is that when I have more than 17 rows of data in the grid, a vertical scrollbar will appear (which is what I want).  However, the vertical scrollbar hides SortGlyph triangle if I happen to be sorting on the last column in the grid.  The user won't be able to see the sort direction.  This is not an issue if I sort on other columns.  I would like the columns to adjust properly (width-wise) when the vertical scrollbar appears so that I can see the SortGlyph indicator at all times.
NOTE: I only show a vertical scroll (not horz scrollbar) for the grid.  My form is not sizable and uses FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D.  The grid is set to DockStyle.Fill.

Some relevent code:

```
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment =DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;

this.GridView_DocumentStatus.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.MultiSelect = false;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.ReadOnly = true;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
this.GridView_DocumentStatus.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

I must have some setting wrong causing this effect.  -OR- Is this something I have to micro-manage by manually adjusting the columns myself (that would suck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout setting of your last column to fill, which will readjust the column width when the vertical scroll bar appears:

```
Column6.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
Column6.FillWeight = 100;
```